# How to add an extra field on infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am using sP 2013. i copy and create the built-in workflow : Approval - sharepoint 2010. In this workflow, there is infopath form.

[image: 123046-image.png]

Now i want to add a new people picker control in the form, just like "request by" :

[image: 122997-image.png]

But i do not know how to add a field to bind this control, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo about customizing the approval form, you can take a reference to it: [Updating the Task Approval Form for the “Out of Box” SharePoint Approval Workflow](https://threewill.com/updating-task-approval-form-box-sharepoint-approval-workflow/).